# jQuery: problem with sortable items: can't be dropped onto empty lists

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Here is an example double list thing: http://jsfiddle.net/xhdUW/

If one of the parent lists already has content, the list items will transfer between the parent lists easily. But if one of the parent lists is empty, the list items will not go into the empty parent list.

The docs on .sortable say that transferring to empty lists should be enabled by default: http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#empty-lists , though, even when I specify dropOnEmpty: true, I get the same behavior.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Your empty list have no height and no vertical padding.
Try to add something from list:
padding-top
padding-bottom
min-height

Comment: is there a way I could do that only when I have a draggable item over the list?

Comment: You can try to change height of empty list from out event callback. But i'm not sure.

Comment: Can't express how much time it took me to find this out. Thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 4):

You have heavily abused the sortable API. See http://jsfiddle.net/6xkQE/ how it gets done right.

1. You have to use `connectWith` with what you want to connect!
2. As @hadvig mentioned, you have to set `min-height`!

Comment: I mean your first call to sortable. It should have been `$j('.section-holder').sortable({connectWith: '.section-holder',...` to get it work. See my fiddle.

Comment: Your fiddle only works if one item is in the list: I added another item: http://jsfiddle.net/6xkQE/1/